# Pass select value to PHP: $_POST empty

Tags: php, jquery

I'm reading a lot of discussion here to find a solution to my issue (for example: [how to pass the id value of a select list in a form using post or get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322847/how-to-pass-the-id-value-of-a-select-list-in-a-form-using-post-or-get)) but for me is not working.

I have a table with a form inside every row:

```
<select name="form_type" class="textselect">
        <?php foreach($SContentType as $key => $val){ ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php if($thisObjs[$k]['type']==$key) echo "SELECTED" ?>><?php echo $val ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

When I try to get the `$_POST` value I have all the variables except the `Select`.

Here is my `$_POST` print

```
 Array ( 
      [a] => ACT_ARTICLES 
      [p] => SUBACT_MODIMAGE 
      [form_id] => 6454
      [obj_id] => 8754 
      [form_description] => )
```

As you can see I have all the variables of the form except form_type, the variable of the select.

Comment: We need to see some context of the form. The select should be there.

Comment: Check and see if you did not close the form tag before your select box.

Comment: First of all I am guessing the `$SContentType` is not empty. Also you could try using `selected="selected"` instead of `SELECTED`. Could you post the entire form here, as the problem might be propagating from somewhere else inside your form.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the select boxes, your code should be working fine. Is it placed within `<form>` and `</form>` tags?

It may have something to do with your multiple table rows. Try doing:

```
<select name="form_type[]">
```

Does it show up now?

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question as jquery, here is a jquery way to do it. The `..` is for any specific class or id you want to give for more specific DOM element.

```
$(".textselect .. option:selected").text()
```